Population impacts on temperature
By what amount (if any) would ambient temperature sink if a metropolitan area (lets say ~12M people) would be reduced to a fraction of its population (lets say ~10k) by an apocalyptic event.
I'm thinking body heat, electric current consumption, combustion engines, ...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Giving us a specific location to work with as an example would help tremendously. For example, Los Angeles, USA (pop 12.5M) is oceanfront and Moscow, RUS (pop 12.4M) is inland. That makes a HUGE difference. Surrounding vegetation, prevailing winds, ambient humidity, distance to food sources... There's a lot of variables to consider without picking a specific example to work with.

See also: the effects on climate and pollution levels when most humans were suddenly stuck inside and advised heavily against using their cars/leaving their homes at all a few years ago. This would probably be an instance of that, but on steroids.

No effect
As an example, New York City gets about 4 kWh of solar insolation per square meter per day. At about 1000 square kilometers, the city gets about 4x109 GWh of solar energy per day.
The electrical usage of NYC is about 5500MW, or 132GWh per day.
A human body produces about 100W of heat. 12 million people will produce 1200MW, or 28.8GWh of energy per day.
The total electrical usage and human heat output of New York is just 0.000003% of the solar energy received by the city. This figure won't climb much more by including all cars, batteries, or other forms of energy storage. Eliminating all the people and the waste heat they generate will have virtually no effect whatsoever on the local temperature. The sun dumps far, far more energy onto the earth's surface than humans do.
Note that this assumes the populations basically just vanishes while leaving the city behind as it was before. The city will of course decay and be reclaimed by nature, and as the city itself vanishes, so will the urban heat island effect. But simply reducing the population and keeping the city the same would have virtually zero effect.

The ground which is NYC is going to get that much solar insolation per square meter per day whether it's "concrete and steel" or "grass and trees".  But the "concrete and steel" creates a noticeable heat island effect.  THAT is what must be measured, not the total insolation.

@RonJohn The heat island effect depends very little on how many people inhabit the city or whether they're driving cars or using electricity. I'm not addressing the time scale where the city is reclaimed by nature and becomes not a city anymore. If all the people vanished from NYC tomorrow, there would be zero effect on the temperature. It's not the people that cause heat islands, it's the city itself. If the city goes away, so does the heat island. But this question just asks about reducing population.

I said nothing about population; only concrete and steel, which is hust what you poorly stated later: “it’s the city itself”. (What about the city? The concrete and steel.  And asphalt.  Forgot to mention that.). Thus, the only purpose of your comment is to show that you did not understand my comment.

@RonJohn Apparently I still don't understand it. The concrete, steel, and asphalt of the city is there whether the population has reduced by 99% or not. There is no scenario where we should be comparing against grass and trees. New York City is indeed hotter than an open field, but I fail to see how that's relevant. The question isn't about comparing the temperatures of a large city that's mostly concrete and a hamlet that's mostly grass. It's about whether the presence of people makes a city hotter - it doesn't, their contribution is totally swamped by the Sun (whether the UHI exists or not).

@RonJohn Basically, the point is that putting 12 million people anywhere, whether into an open field or a concrete jungle, will have no effect whatsoever on the local temperature. We have no real need to measure the heat island effect, it doesn't change the effect of reducing the population by 99%. I understand you didn't mention population, but that's kind of the point of the question.

Depending on the metropolitan area you could inadvertently kill 90% of the world population. Assuming you pick well and don't doom civilisation, the way that the physical buildings soak up solar radiation has a much bigger effect than the population using the city does. The effects of removing the people and their vehicles, lights, heating etc... is going to be most notable in the hour or so just before dawn when the city has shed most of its adsorbed solar energy. As the urban heat island effect totals less than 3°C(10°F) and is primarily caused by lack of vegetation and increased heat adsorption by the built surfaces that replace it, you're probably looking at 1°C or less of change from only removing the majority of people from the space.
As a note removing that much of the population will probably result in the city burning down in short order due to the lack of maintenance workers etc... Assuming it stayed depopulated that is.

And vegetation will eventually take over reducing the heat island effect.

@DavidR Some places yes that will be a noticeable process on a human timescale, other cities it'll take a very long time due to the combination of size, impervious cover percentage and local weather conditions, particularly wind.

Yep. If the place is quite windy, I expect that fires will change much of the landscape. Then, dust will blow in. That gives a basis to start vegetating the place. The next question is how much rain.

It's hard if not impossible to give a precise value considering you give no details, but for sure the urban heat island is measurable:

Urban areas usually experience the urban heat island (UHI) effect, that is, they are significantly warmer than surrounding rural areas. The temperature difference is usually larger at night than during the day, and is most apparent when winds are weak, under block conditions, noticeably during the summer and winter.


The phenomenon was first investigated and described by Luke Howard in the 1810s, although he was not the one to name the phenomenon. A description of the very first report of the UHI by Luke Howard said that the urban center of London was warmer at night than the surrounding countryside by 2.1 °C (3.7 °F).

Interestingly, it seems that geometry of the buildings and coverage of the surfaces play a major role in determining the effect, meaning that, as long as vegetation has not taken over the now almost empty city (a la I am legend) there will be still a tangible effect on keeping the city warmer.
